# Text positioning issue with fixed and absolute positioning

Tags: css, position

On a website I am creating I wanted the navigation bar and an image placed just below it to fill the complete width of the screen with no padding. I have used a fixed position for the navigation bar and an absolute position for the image which works. However now I want to add some text under the image but it positions itself in the top right corner of the page, what do i need to change to make the text position itself under the image?

Here is my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(47,47,47);
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: rgb(230,230,230);

}
ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 518px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
li{
    float: left;
}
li a{
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 32px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(230,230,230);

}
li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(47,47,47);
}
li a:active {
    background-color: rgb(223, 66, 68)
}

nav{
    background-color: rgb(6,6,6);
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
#logo{

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  

    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>

    <h1>About me</h1>


</body>
```

Comment: We will also need your relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put image and text under one div and give css which is given to image, give it to that new div. i.e. `position:absolute` to new created div.

like:

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(47,47,47);
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: rgb(230,230,230);

}
ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    width: 518px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
li{
    float: left;
}
li a{
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    padding: 32px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(230,230,230);

}
li a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(47,47,47);
}
li a:active {
    background-color: rgb(223, 66, 68)
}

nav{
    background-color: rgb(6,6,6);
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.belowDiv{

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left:0px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

```html
  <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>  

<div class="belowDiv">
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png"/>
  <h1>About me</h1>
</div>
```